# Google Kubernetes Engine: ErrImagePull: Too Many Links

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

This seems to be an issue with hard link limits in coreos (?) that should have been resolved with Docker overlayfs2.  We don't know why this is occurring in kubernetes (1.8) however since it should be automatically garbage collecting old images.

Any ideas?

Error from kubectl describe:

```
Warning  Failed                 2m               kubelet, gke-dev-ctp-default-pool-08c10bb8-f2d1  

Failed to pull image "gcr.io/my-group/my-image:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to register layer: link /var/lib/docker/overlay/2f8076d1832a8a60086988b73fd2d8eec7ba38e62e9615f592d048d72d48a227/root/usr/libexec/git-core/git-merge-tree /var/lib/docker/overlay/0c6044f911da4845bac37bad4d1fcf9a7e03a7b8242cf2bf8da46e17ec23e3f9/tmproot518352995/usr/libexec/git-core/git-merge-tree: too many links
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GKE is currently not using overlayfs2. They are working on enabling this feature in GKE version 1.9 along with the new docker version.

The workaround is to remove all the unused images manually using the following method:

- Check current number of images

> $ docker images | wc -l

- remove the unused images

> $ docker image prune -a

- Check new number of images

> $ docker images | wc -l

Comment: So to be clear, SSH into each node and docker prune?

Comment: Yes, you have to run it in each affected node. If you have too many nodes, start with the ones where you receive the message and then you can prioritize nodes with more disk usage.

Comment: Note: this only works on newer versions of docker supporting the `prune` command.  Otherwise, best to use something like [spotify/docker-gc](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc#running-as-a-docker-image)